# Explore php man page with manpageview in vim

Tags: vim

This feature isn't working like it supposed to work.

Example:

I write substr and I want open man page about substr command but when I hit K (cursor is on substr command) it shows

```
***warning*** sorry, no manpage exists for <substr>
```

but when I write

```
:Man substr.php
```

it shows substr description properly.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/View_PHP_documentation_for_current_word) details how to open the PHP.net documentation for the keyword under the cursor, using the browser:

```
function OpenPHPManual(keyword)
  let firefox = '/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin'
  " you will need to create this profile in firefox
  let profile = 'Profile for PHP Manual'
  let url = 'http://www.php.net/' . a:keyword
  exec '!' . firefox . ' -p "' . profile . '" "' . url . '"'
endfunction
noremap gd :call OpenPHPManual(expand('<cword>'))<CR>
```

Or, with `lynx(1)`:

```
function OpenPHPManual(keyword)
  let web = 'lynx -accept_all_cookies --cookie_file=/home/jon/.lynx_cookies --cookie_save_file=/home/jon/.lynx_cookies --cookies'
  let url = 'http://jp2.php.net/' . a:keyword
  exec '!' . web . ' "' . url . '"'
endfunction
```

Comment: I'm really interested on making the "K" command work with local manual pages, though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to nstall the **elinks** web browser.

See **help manpageviewphp** for details.